# Python - sub for multiple variables

Tags: python, regex

What would be elegant/pythonic way to pass multiple string variables through a `sub`? I need to pass multiple varialbes to `sub` to replace string chunk that appears in every single one of them.

My working code which I want to avoid:

```
import re

txt = "aaa"
txt2 = "aaaCCC"

txt = re.sub(r'aaa', 'bbb', txt)
txt2 = re.sub(r'aaa', 'bbb', txt2)

print(txt)
print(txt2)
```

Comment: Looks like you may need a loop

Comment: Or maybe list comprehension?

Comment: What do you expect it to look like, approximately?

Comment: @marcin2x4 That is a loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

txt = "aaa"
txt2 = "aaaCCC"

original = [txt, txt2]

subbed = [re.sub(r'aaa', 'bbb', x) for x in original]

print(subbed[0])
print(subbed[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `functools.partial` to create a `map`pable function:

```
mappable = functools.partial(re.sub, 'aaa', 'bbb')
```

This is roughly equivalent to doing

```
mappable = lambda t: re.sub('aaa', 'bbb', t)
```

The main differences are that `partial` makes a proper function wrapper with a fancy name and other attributes based on the underlying function.

You can map with a `map` or a comprehension:

```
txt, txt2 = map(mappable, (txt, txt2))
```

Unpacking the generator evaluates it. A list comprehension does the same:

```
result = [mappable(t) for t in (txt, txt2)]
```